# Users create a draft (save draft module) but subsequently can't publish node

Tags: users, nodes

Using Drupal 7: users on my site are creating drafts (using the Save Draft module) but subsequently when editing and clicking publish the node never publishes. After clicking publish node remain unpublished and the status remains at 0 in the db node table.

I have also disable the save Draft module but still cannot publish the drafts.

Permissions are all setup correctly.

Very confused. Please help.

Danny.

Comment: I had setup 'form events' for this node using the rules module. Having disabled this feature the daft/publishing seems be to working now. I wasn't actually using the form event so for now this seems to have solved my problem.